# limit of number of dynamic fields in Solr 4.x

Tags: solr

I want to use Solr 4.x to enable search through around 20,000 fields;

These fields are mostly static (i.e. they are always the same), but sometimes new ones will be added.
I think creating a schema.xml for 20,000 fields is unfeasible (too big, and wouldnt handle adding new ones).
I think the right solution for this is to use dynamic fields. But can Solr 4.x handle 20,000 dynamic fields ? 
The only doc i found was from Datastax, that says the limit is 1024 dynamic fields per row ..
(http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.0/search/dse_search_schema)

thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

According to the post [Maximum number of fields allowed in a Solr document](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Maximum-number-of-fields-allowed-in-a-Solr-document-td505435.html) from the Solr Users Mailing List:

> There is no build-in limit.  The limit is going to be dictated by your hardware resources.